# MVC3 Speed on production iis7

Tags: performance, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, windows-server-2008, pagespeed

I have an MVC3 application which is working fast in my dev environment (even when pointed at the production database). However, when I publish the application and move it onto the production iis7 environment it runs at a snails pace. I understand that the inital load can take a few seconds as the application pool starts up, but this is taking 20+ seconds. Then will be fast for a few clicks and the next click will again take 20+ seconds.

I've put in the MVCMiniPorifler and it doesn't look like the database is causing problems. But, I also can't see what is causing the problem. I can hit the same page multiple times and it comes back in a second or 2 and then suddenly that same page will take 20+ seconds to respond.

Has anyone seen this sort of behaviour before? Any help would be greatly appreciated and I'm not sure what to try next.

Comment: What are your cache settings? in the web.config and on the actions?

Comment: I've tried adding caching and it has speeded things up a bit, but I want to know what the underlying problem is. The website is just a small internal project, so will only have 4-5 users. Caching seems like a lot of overkill for a small project. There's currently no caching on actions and no caching mentioned in the web.config.

Comment: In your dev environment do you use IIS or cassini/IIS express? And do you do work intensively with files on the server?

Comment: I use Cassini in my dev environment. Not sure what you mean about working intensively with files on the server? There are 2 places where you can upload/download a file, but apart from that, everything is pretty simple CRUD operations.

Comment: I've now got the app working with IIS7 locally and am seeing the same behaviour. The page I just loaded took 23 seconds, but the MVCMiniProfiler said 643.2ms at the top... I'm very confused by this

Comment: Look in the event logs of your production server. There might be issues with IIS recycling your app domain/appPool, something like that.

Comment: Have you put any complex logic in your views?

Comment: Agree with @GiscardBiamby sounds like an IIS issue

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the other web apps running on your production server are locking required resources. Is there a common file or folder that multiple sites utilize? Are you sharing the app pool between any of the sites?